# python Selenium Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to start with proxy server. I don't know why I'm getting this error.
how can i solve it?

selenium4
python3.10
chromedriver 104.0

```
    options2 = {
        'proxy': {
            'https': 'http://****:*****.@gw.ntnt.ip:5959',
            'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'  
        }
    }


    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    # options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options,seleniumwire_options=options2)
    driver.get("https://www.whatsmyip.org/")
    time.sleep(40)
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eymen\PycharmProjects\snapcreator2t\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    create()
  File "C:\Users\Eymen\PycharmProjects\snapcreator2t\main.py", line 34, in create
    driver.get("https://www.whatsmyip.org/")
  File "C:\Users\Eymen\PycharmProjects\snapcreator2t\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Eymen\PycharmProjects\snapcreator2t\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Eymen\PycharmProjects\snapcreator2t\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.102)
```

Comment: Looks like the proxy you have provided is not connecting, and hence the tunnel is not created

Comment: In chrome version `104.0.5112.102` I also had this problem, it didn't happen before.

Comment: Having the same issue but only for a particular site. The proxy is working.